# How should I organize my directory structure when using CMake with C++ inheritance?

Tags: c++, cmake, directory-structure

Currently I have a directory structure that looks like the following

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Base
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── base.h
│   └── src
│       └── base.cpp
├── Derived
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── derived.h
│   └── src
│       └── derived.cpp
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

and the **CMakeLists.txt** files looking like

#### ./CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

project(MyProj)

add_subdirectory(Base)
add_subdirectory(Derived)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main Base)
target_link_libraries(main Derived)
```

#### ./Base/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Base STATIC src/base.cpp)
target_include_directories(Base PUBLIC include)
```

#### ./Derived/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Derived STATIC src/derived.cpp)
target_include_directories(Derived PUBLIC include)
target_link_libraries(Derived Base)
```

I want to know if this is an appropriate way to structure a CMake project when using inheritance in C++. If there is a more idiomatic way to structure this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I think this is largely up to opinion, and would imagine it gets closed on that basis. I personally think that this directory structure is only feasible for smaller projects. If you really want them separate, then maybe an "api" folder that holds all your base classes (or just their headers; it really is up to you and your preferences) and a separate "impl" or whatever for leaf classes.

Comment: I don't understand how inheritance is connected to a make file (except for header file dependencies).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, its also the linking part I am trying to deal with. If I keep extending this, say make another class that inherits from Derived, then I have to make a new CMakeLists.txt file then link and include against these files. I don't have a problem doing this, but it does not seem very maintainable for larger projects as sweenish described.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance.  You would have the same issue for different classes / objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to build two libraries, and an executable, then that is what your structure achieves. I would however recommend thinking why you are doing that, and perhaps consider whether it would be simpler to instead have both classes in a single library.

> If I keep extending this, say make another class that inherits from Derived, then I have to make a new CMakeLists.txt file then link and include against these files. I don't have a problem doing this, but it does not seem very maintainable for larger projects

No, you don't have to make a new CMakeLists.txt unless you add a new target. You don't necessarily need more than a single target for a project.

A target (be it executable or a library) is not limited to having only one translation unit.

My personal preference for small project is three (or two) targets: A library containing all functionality, a main executable with `int main()` that does nothing except invoke the library (if the project is an executable rather than just the library), and a test executable with `int main()` from a test framework. The library can optionally be split to smaller pieces if it has parts that are reusable in other projects.

---

> ```
> set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
> ```

prefer target specific properties instead:

```
set_target_properties(
    Base PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11

    # use unless you also support older standards
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
```

The dependees will inherit the property, but you can set it explicitly in each for potentially lesser chance of breakage in case you later decide to not use the base library.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a library for each class is overkill and might slow down compilation on some build systems.

On some of my projects, I have over 300 types, not counting templates and lambdas. I cannot imagine creating a library for each classes.

> I want to know if this is an appropriate way to structure a CMake project when using inheritance in C++

The features you are using should not change how the code is organised physically. Instead, base your file layout in logical self contained part of your code with clear dependencies between each parts.

The only nitpick: Use this form to link libraries together:

```
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC Base) # or private
```

The rest of your CMake make good use of the target based API. The only thing I would change would be to be less fine grained in term of what constitute a library.